# Attachments in Papercut

Tags: c#, email, smtp, attachment, mailmessage

I am currently using [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com) in order to test sending emails over an SMTP server connection in C#.

The emails that I need to send have files attached to them however the files do not seem to appear when I view the email on Papercut. I am sure the files are being attached properly to the email as I can see them in the attachment part of the MailMessage Object. My Question is, does Papercut support emails with attachments or does it just show the email and truncate the attachment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you view the message in the Papercut interface, right under the subject line you will see some headings: Message,Headers,Body,Sections,Raw. Click the "Sections" header. You will then see a list of items to select from, and if there is an attachment then one of them will be the attachment. You can right click and Save as or double-click to open it.

Comment: Great! If you want to mark my answer as the correct answer, that would be appreciated!